# Implication of Exhaustive Events

Tags: probability

In a certain problem, it is given that A=B’. There are also events C and D. There are other various probabilities given but no context (dice, etc.)
The solution to this problem is predicated on reading from A=B’ that this implies that A and B are exhaustive events. Is this determinable simply from A=B’? If so, how?

Comment: Well, if $A=B'$ then $B=A'$, so yes.

Comment: But why is this the case? Especially as there are other events...

Comment: The other events have nothing to do with it.  To say that $A=B'$ means that $A$ is the event "not $B$".  But not matter what happens we either have $B$ or not $B$.  Thus $B,B'$ are exhaustive so $B,A$ are exhaustive.